# Solve a system of equations $x+y+z＝1, x^2+y^2+z^2＝3, x^3+y^3+z^3＝1$

Tags: systems-of-equations

Does this system have infinitely many solutions. Because evident solution is $1,-1,1$ . And I reached till condition $xyz=-1$ with algebraic transformations. I  got that $x^2+y^2+z^2+2(xy+yz+zx)=1$ and from the second equation got $xy+yz+zx=-1$. Then got from $(x^3+y^3+z^3)-3xyz=(x+y+z)(x^2+y^2+z^2-xy-yz-xz)$, that $xyz=-1$. I tried to  return with the shift $x=-1/yz$ back to equations, however, I cannot get concrete solutions, does anyone have an idea how to proceed?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Thank you i will use that next time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let\begin{align}P(\lambda)&=(\lambda-x)(\lambda-y)(\lambda-z)\\&=\lambda^3-(x+y+z)\lambda^2+(xy+xz+yz)\lambda-xyz\\&=\lambda^3-\lambda^2-\lambda+1.\end{align}Then $x$, $y$, and $z$ are the roots of $P(\lambda)$. But\begin{align}P(\lambda)=0&\iff\lambda^3-\lambda^2-\lambda+1=0\\&\iff\lambda^2(\lambda-1)-(\lambda-1)=0\\&\iff(\lambda^2-1)(\lambda-1)=0\\&\iff(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+1)=0.\end{align}Therefore, the solutions are$$(x,y,z)=(1,1,-1),\ (x,y,z)=(1,-1,1)\text{, and }(x,y,z)=(-1,1,1).$$

Comment: doesn't $(\lambda-1)^2(\lambda+1)=0$ imply $x=y=1$ and $z=-1$?

Comment: @ManjoyDas Why not $x=z=1$ and $y=-1$?

Comment: yeah. The factors can switch places among themselves

Comment: Sorry i dont get it how we related this equation with the system?- José Carlos Santos

Comment: @Maca I have expanded my answer. Is it clear now?

Comment: @Maca See [Vieta's formulas](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) . This will help you .

Comment: @lone student Are Vietas formulas not for the equations with one unknown value.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos I get it how we got till the solution -1,1,1 but i dont get it how to explain solution of a system through p(/lambda) sorry i know i am sure dumb for this but can you explain me please

Comment: @Maca The numbers that you are after are $x$, $y$, and $z$. But $P(\lambda)=(\lambda-x)(\lambda-y)(\lambda-z)$. Therefore, the numbers that you are after are the roots of $P(\lambda)$, which turn out to be $1$, $1$, and $-1$.